# Linux desktop freezes caused by Nouveau driver

Tags: debian, freeze, x-server, nouveau

Its really annoying - every now and then the desktop completely freezes and sometimes even the UI look like a tetris game or something. And the keboard and mouse cannot be used so I have to use a SSH client from my android (Juice) to kill the userprocess i.e log out. This means I lose all open applications and not the least time. Counting the times the last hour this occurred 5 times, mostly when a webbrowser is open but the freezing is very very erratic.

According to the syslog the opensource nouveau-driver seems to be involved and my question is how I can get rid of this annoying problem? I have googled pretty much about the issue and the problem seems to be more or less common but I cannot find any trustly solution. For instance - can I replace the nouveau-driver for NVIDIA's or is it risky? Please, if there is a safe strategy I would be more than happy. Any other solution such as changing desktop? If those solutions are bad - and the desktop freezes, is there any other bash commands than the following:

```
pkill -KILL -u user
```

output from inxi -Fxz

```
 System:    Host: mx Kernel: 4.19.0-11-amd64 x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 8.3.0 
       Desktop: Xfce 4.14.2 Distro: MX-19.2_x64 patito feo May 31  2020 
        base: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) 
 Machine:   Type: Desktop System: Dell product: XPS 8700 v: N/A serial: <filter> 
       Mobo: Dell model: 0KWVT8 v: A03 serial: <filter> BIOS: Dell v: A08 date: 04/16/2014 
 CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i7-4790 bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Haswell 
       rev: 3 L2 cache: 8192 KiB 
       flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 57466 
       Speed: 1197 MHz min/max: 800/4000 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1197 2: 1198 3: 1198 
       4: 1197 5: 1195 6: 1199 7: 1199 8: 1198 
 Graphics:  Device-1: NVIDIA GK208 [GeForce GT 720] driver: nouveau v: kernel bus ID: 01:00.0 
       Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.4 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa 
       resolution: 2560x1440~60Hz 
       OpenGL: renderer: NV108 v: 4.3 Mesa 18.3.6 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel 8 Series/C220 Series High Definition Audio vendor: Dell 
       driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1b.0 
       Device-2: NVIDIA GK208 HDMI/DP Audio driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 01:00.1 
       Sound Server: ALSA v: k4.19.0-11-amd64 
Network:   Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Dell 
       driver: r8169 v: kernel port: d000 bus ID: 03:00.0 
       IF: eth0 state: down mac: <filter> 
       Device-2: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter vendor: Dell driver: ath9k 
       v: kernel port: d000 bus ID: 04:00.0 
       IF: wlan0 state: up mac: <filter> 
       Device-3: Qualcomm Atheros type: USB driver: btusb bus ID: 1-13:5 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 1.36 TiB used: 9.25 GiB (0.7%) 
       ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Seagate model: ST1000DM003-1CH162 size: 931.51 GiB temp: 32 C 
       ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: Samsung model: SSD 860 EVO mSATA 500GB size: 465.76 GiB 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 287.37 GiB used: 9.25 GiB (3.2%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda3 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 29.8 C mobo: 27.8 C gpu: nouveau temp: 62 C 
       Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 249 Uptime: 20h 54m Memory: 15.62 GiB used: 1.79 GiB (11.5%) 
       Init: SysVinit runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 8.3.0 Shell: bash v: 5.0.3 inxi: 3.0.36
```

screenshots

1

[image]

2

[image]

3

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR

1. You can replace it, and it's ok.

Step to do:

1. switch off nouveau.
2. install proprietary nvidia, [link](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-nvidia-driver-latest-proprietary-driver/)
3. remove `nouveau.modeset = 0`

Yes you can replace the nouveau-driver and I suggest you to do so if you cannot fix the build in ones. you can turn off nouveau by clicking e when you are in grub (which you may select run linux or recovery or other os). after that, you need to add `nouveau.modeset = 0` in `linux` line (tips, you can click `end` key in keyboard to move cursor to the end of line). and then, you can click X which means run the current grub setup temporarily.

You may also set grub permanently by editing `/etc/default/grub` with string I mention above ― nouveau one. but you need to run `sudo upgrade-grub` after that.

after that, you can install proprietary driver. there is bunch of tutorial in the search engines. because you use debian, maybe you can refer [this](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-nvidia-driver-on-debian-10-buster-linux) site.

if nvidia driver is successfully installed, make sure to remove the nouveau.modeset if edit the `/etc/default/grub`

Comment: thanks I'll look into this and may accept the answer If I success with this issue

Comment: may I ask where **linux line** is in the grub file, that is where to put the syntax. I am now ready to follow your steps

Comment: I may have found it but when booting I got the error message **noveau: ´ invalid for parameter 'modeset'**. When in grubfile = equals the key **´** i.e the key to the left of backspace

Comment: it is `nouveau.modeset = 0` not `noveau`

refer to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1122021/how-do-i-add-code-below-to-the-end-of-linux-kernel-flags-in-grub) it might help you out.

if it still having an error, try removing space around `=`

Comment: oops, just a typo in my comment, I know its nouveau :-). I'll try again